# Script para fazer aparecer uma div

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tenho um cadastro de usuários em minha aplicação, quando clico em cadastrar queria que mostrar uma mensagem. Esse tratamento todo eu já estou fazendo e jogando a mensagem na minha ViewBag.Message. Como faço pra mostrar essa DIV ao clicar no botão cadastrar ?

Comment: se você mostrar a div, a mensagem já vai aparecer automaticamente ?

Comment: Sim, pois a minha ViewBag.Message fica dentro da div.

Answer (score 4):

Após clicar em cadastrar, você tem algumas maneiras de mostrar a div:

1ª -> `$("#idDiv").show();`

2ª -> `document.getElementById('idDiv').style.display = 'block';`

3ª -> `$("#idDiv").css("display", "block");`

Acredito que a primeira funcione.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode verificar se a `ViewBag.Message` não está vazia, então exibir uma mensagem.

Abaixo segue um exemplo usando o jQueryUI:

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string mensagem)
        {               
            ViewBag.Messagem = mensagem;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    var mensagem = string.Empty;
    if (ViewBag.Messagem != null) {
        mensagem = ViewBag.Messagem.ToString();
    }   
}

<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <input type="hidden" name="mensagem" value="Hello World!"></input>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        }
        <div id="mensagem">
        </div>
        <!-- Este script deveria está em um arquivo e não inline -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var mensagem = document.getElementById("mensagem");
            $(function () {
                $(mensagem).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true
                });             
            });
            var exibirMensagem = function (msg) {
                mensagem.innerHTML = msg;
                $(mensagem).dialog("open");
            }
        </script>
        @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mensagem)) {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                exibirMensagem("@ViewBag.Messagem");
            });
        </script>
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

Note que o método `exibirMensagem` só é chamado se `ViewBag.Messagem` possuir um valor.

Segue um fiddle:
[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K0QDhd)